# User Placed Text on a picturebox in c#

Tags: c#, text, textbox, drawstring

I am trying to make a tool that allows me to choose a certain location on a picturebox to put text from a textbox on. It will need to be able to place multiple different texts on the picturebox and then be able to be deleted. This is my current code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TextboxTool
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
        }

        private void textBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Visible = true;
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);
            G.DrawString(textBox1.Text, new Font("Tahoma", 40), Brushes.Black, new Point(MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y));
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment i can type the text in the textbox, but can't draw the string on the picturebox and choose its location. I have a button which is meant to confirm the text written is right and then allow the user to choose its location. Please can someone help me sort this code out?

Thanks-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `MousePosition` property is relative to the screen, not the `PictureBox`.

You should handle the `MouseClick` event and draw the string at `e.X` and `e.Y`.
Alternatively, you can call `pictureBox1.PointToClient` to transform screen coordinates to control-relative coordinates.

Also, you should dispose the `Graphics` object in a `using` statement.

Finally, I'm pretty sure you'll need to call `pictureBox1.Invalidate()` after modifying the image to force it to repaint.